# Add a '.' for every string in a list of lists, if string[-1] != '.'

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
text_lst = [['this is a string.','this is a string2'],['this is not a string'],['this is a string with numbers!','that is all!']]
```

I need to add a `.` for every string that does not end with a `.`. Below is my code:

```
new_lst = []
for x in text_lst:
    for x1 in x:
        if x1[-1] != '.':
            new_lst.append(x1 + '.')
        else:
            new_lst.append(x1)
```

However, it returns a weird combination of strings and list:

```
[['this is a string.', 'this is a string2'],
 'this is a string2.',
 'this is not a string.',
 'this is a string with numbers!.',
 'that is all!.']
```

I'm expecting this type of result:

```
[['this is a string.', 'this is a string2.'],
 ['this is not a string.'],
 ['this is a string with numbers!', 'that is all!']]
```

Can you kindly let me know what did I do wrong?

Edit:
I used the wrong variable, instead of appending `x1`, I append `x`. Here's the result:

```
['this is a string.',
 'this is a string2.',
 'this is not a string.',
 'this is a string with numbers!.',
 'that is all!.']
```

However, any suggestion on how to preserve the list of lists format like the original one?

Comment: `for every string that does not end with a .` it seems like you don't want to add a period when the string ends with `!` also. What about `?` or `:` or `,`? -- it's a little underspecified.

Comment: I think you want `else: new_lst.append(x1)` (the current item) and not `new_lst.append(x)` (the entire list)

Comment: Oh my God, I'm so stupid. It should have been `x1`. However, it leads to a new question though, how can I preserve the list of lists format after that?

Comment: You can preserve the list of lists with a simple list comprehension. This doesn't solve the problems of the other ending punctuation, however: `[[s if s.endswith('.') else s + '.' for s in l] for l in text_lst ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first learn how to add a dot to a text:

```py
def add_dot(text):
    if text.endswith(("!", ".")):
        return text
    return text + "."
```

Once we have this function, we can combine it with list comprehension:

```py
[
    [add_dot(text) for text in inner_list]
    for inner_list in text_lst
]
```

Given your sample input, the output will be:

```py
[['this is a string.', 'this is a string2.'],
 ['this is not a string.'],
 ['this is a string with numbers!', 'that is all!']]
```

## Update

I took a closer look at the OP's code and found out why it does not produce the desired result: That code did not create the inner list, so here is a modification of the OP's code with variables renamed:

```py
new_list = []
for inner_list in text_lst:
    new_inner_list = []
    new_list.append(new_inner_list)
    for text in inner_list:
        if text[-1] not in "!.":
            new_inner_list.append(text + '.')
        else:
            new_inner_list.append(text)
```